# Android can't open file, FileNotFoundException(Permission denied), but PermissionRead is granted

Tags: android, file-not-found

Android can't open file with FileNotFoundException(Permission denied), but PermissionRead is granted.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/obb/"file detailed path": open
>   failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
>
> obb file is ERROR_ALREADY_MOUNTED.

```
int readPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, mPermissions[0]);
int writePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, mPermissions[1]);

readPermission == 0;
writePermission == 0;
```

**PermissionRead is granted.**

Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Android OS ver.6.0 device.

why...?

Answer (score 2):

Try to give runtime permission

```
int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // We don't have permission so prompt the user
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            activity,
            PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
            REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

have you implemented runtime permission?,
first you grant manually storage permission from settings and check exception occur or not, if not then you have mistake in permission implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answers...

This is a very strange phenomenon.
Once, I was able to fix it to work properly.

## Conclusion: Solution

Create an obb file with jobb command with the same name as renamed on Google Play side.

That is...Before the fix was done like this.(example)

```
jobb -pn com.test.testapp -pv 1 -d ./myfiles -o main1.obb
```

And if you upload "main1.obb" to Google Play, "main.1.com.test.testapp.obb" will be downloaded along with apk download.

But this is not good.

After the correction, it was programmed like this.

```
jobb -pn com.test.testapp -pv 1 -d ./myfiles -o main.1.com.test.testapp.obb
```

## Why: Reasons to fix

I thought that there was a problem with obb mount when the following error occurred:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/obb/"file detailed path": open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

So I tried to unmount obb after the error.
Then an error came back.

```
public static final int ERROR_PERMISSION_DENIED = 25;
```

If I try to unmount an already mounted obb, it is a permission error.
This is strange.

As I looked it up on the Internet, the problem is obb filename made with the jobb command? Or package name? It was said that it occurred.

Therefore, I changed the obb file name generated by the jobb command.
There is no problem with this. Of course, "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" has always acquired.

I did not understand anything more.
Just the application is working correctly.

Thank you.